# Facing issues on getting multiple marker through DynamoDb

Tags: android, google-maps, amazon-dynamodb, google-maps-markers, kml

I am new to android and working on a map based application where i want to show multiple markers (around 1000 or more), i have completed all the steps with dynamo db and stored the result in the list. Now when i googled about showing multiple marker in map, I've got a solution that i have to store data in array and then put it inside loop. I have marker stored in string X, Y, and XY.
I want to show in the map. Please go through the code and let me know how to get the values of X,Y, and XY.

Settlements.java

```
private String X;
private String Y;
private String XY;
private String "AreaName"

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "AreaName")
public String getAreaName() {
    return AreaName;
}

public void setAreaName(String AreaName) {
    this.AreaName = AreaName;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "X")
public String getX() {
    return X;
}

public void setX(String x) {
    X = x;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Y")
public String getY() {
    return Y;
}

public void setY(String y) {
    Y = y;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "XY")
public String getXY() {
    return XY;
}

public void setXY(String XY) {
    this.XY = XY;
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.

```
 public class NavigationDrawerPeaceNow extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        OutpostsTable outpostsTable;
        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        private Context mContext;
        private List<SettlementsTable> lstSettlements = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer_peace_now);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.layersiv);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            DDBExecutor.getInstance().getAllSettlements(mContext, new DDBExecutor.OnResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Object result, String message) {
                    lstSettlements.addAll((List<SettlementsTable>) result);



                    }
                }
            });


            ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    try {
                        KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.settlements, getApplicationContext());
                        kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
                        KmlLayer kmlLayer1 = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.outposts, getApplicationContext());
                        kmlLayer1.addLayerToMap();
                        KmlLayer kmlLayer2 = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.settlements_in_pal_nghbrhd_styled, getApplicationContext());
                        kmlLayer2.addLayerToMap();

                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    LatLng israel = new LatLng(31.0461, 34.8516);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(israel).title("israel"));

                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                    CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(31.0461, 34.8516)).zoom(8).tilt(70).build();
                    CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
                }


            });
```

Comment: Are X, Y, and XY  lat,lang and title in here?

Comment: @keshav yes.. they are latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this with the list of `SettlementsTable`

```
for (SettlementsTable settlementsTable :lstSettlements) {
            LatLng latLng=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(settlementsTable.getX()),Double.parseDouble(settlementsTable.getY()));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(settlementsTable.getXY()));
        }
```

Comment: thank you sir, let me check and will up vote this answer.

Comment: its getting crash on Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference

Comment: You need to put this at        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(israel).title("israel"));       line and remove this line